# Having to 'take ownership' of temp install files to install anything

Tags: installation, windows-8.1, windows-installer, temporary-files

For quite a while I have had problems installing files now. Every time they try to install with files stored in appdata the installer will not have permission to read or write the file in appdata even tho the installer is running as an administrator.

To take ownership of the file I followed this: http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/2814-take-ownership-add-context-menu-windows-8-a.html

Any ideas or further information needed? I don't know where to start looking sorry.

Answer (score 2):

When this happens, it usually means the profile is corrupt. If you give yourself a new profile it will fix the issue, but it also means you lose any settings you have set previously unless you have linked to a microsoft account.

If you haven't linked to a microsoft account, the easiest way to reset your profile would be to link it to a microsoft account, perform a profile reset, then log in again, and unlink the microsoft account.

To reset your profile, go to your `control panel`, `system`.

On your left, you'll find `Advanced system settings`

On the `Advanced` tab, click the <kbd>Settings...</kbd> button inside the `User Profiles` frame.

Delete your account here. Do note, in order to delete your account, you have to login with a different administrator account first. If one doesn't exist, create it first.

Once deleted, log back into your account.

If this is too much work, you can try taking ownership of your entire appdata folder, then in addition add your own user to the security and give yourself Full Control. Then go to the <kbd>Advanced</kbd> settings, click <kbd>Change Permissions</kbd> at the bottom and check the `[v]Replace all child object permissions with inheritable permissions from this object` to ensure that the rights will be reset to all folders and subfolders whitin appdata.

Hit <kbd>OK</kbd> to make the changes and wait for it to reset the permissions on all files and folders.

Note that changing the security settings may not fix your issue, but a profile reset will most certainly do.